# static const VS const local variable, which one performs better?

Tags: c++, performance

Let's say that we have two functions:

```
void foo_1(...)
{
  static const unordered_map<int, string> m_1 = {{1, "abc"}, {2, "cde"}, {3, "fgh"}};
  ...
}

void foo_2(...)
{
  const unordered_map<int, string> m_2 = {{1, "abc"}, {2, "cde"}, {3, "fgh"}};
  ...
}
```

Which one will have better performance? Will compiler/optimizer understand that it can make m_2 static and initialize it only once?

Comment: How about profiling both and finding out?

Comment: Compile both and look at generated code. Personally, I doubt the optimizer is smart enough to magically convert the automatic variable into static.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wasn't aware compiler can transform automatic storage duration var into a static one. Isn't that up to us to decide?

Comment: @Ron Under as-if rule, the compiler can do anything as long as the conforming program can't tell the difference. That's the whole basis for optimization.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see. Appreciate it.

Comment: m_1 is faster at runtime, but it will slightly slow down app initialization, I'm quite sure that no optimizer will be able to optimize out the static initialization of a std::map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why I can't say (and don't trust anybody who claims otherwise) which one is **faster** without profiling on a particular system, it is worthy to consider performance implications in both cases, assuming customary optimizations.

In your second case, you will be creating a `std::unordered_map` with every function entrance. I know of no optimizer which might convert this auto variable into static one, and I can't imagine how it even might be possible for a compiler to figure out. The major performance hits there would be memory allocation (quite significant in multithreading environment, much less so in single threaded ones) and a cost of initializing the map with three elements - likely, another memory allocation for map nodes, and possibly memory allocation for strings, unless SSO is enabled on target platform.

First version will not suffer from performance issues described above - it will perform all necessary memory allocations only once, when the function is called first time.

However, it will be affected by something else - since initialization of static locals is thread-safe since 2011, there would be a cost of checking the hidden boolean flag. There is also a question of memory synchronization involved, but since any sane compiler will use double-checked locking here, those questions should not be of relevance. As is, all that remains is the check for the boolean on each entrance and a branch. Hopes are, branch predictor is going to kick in pretty soon and do a good job for us, so all that remains is simple comparison cost, which is pretty much nothing.